# TypeError when compiling openGL with cx_freeze

Tags: python, python-3.3, cx-freeze

I have a small pygame script and I want to compile it; I used this file as setup.py:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "AlGem",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "AlGem",
    executables = [Executable("algem.py", base = "Win32GUI")])
```

but I get a syntax error in one of openGL package files...

> File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\constants.py", line 46 except TypeError, err: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What did I miss?

Comment: `except TypeError, err:` isn't valid in Python 3 - it needs to be `except TypeError as err:`. Check how that file got installed - there might be other things to correct.

Comment: I am having this same exact problem. The strange thing is I built my game last night with no errors; the resulting executable running just fine. When I tried to build another project I started getting this error (on both projects).

Comment: Really though, why would it even be looking in there? openGL is an installed module which pygame does not depend on, and my code makes no references to it! im thinking cx_Freeze is broken, will try a reinstall and check back.

Comment: Something in pygame could be importing OpenGL, even if your code doesn't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clean install of cx_Freeze fixed the problem for me.

Pygame doesn't depend on OpenGL, so there's no reason for cx_Freeze to be snooping around there.